90s or early 2000's movie or TV show about dinosaurs that ends with them in space
I have a distinct childhood memory of the ending to either a TV show or movie that was about cartoon dinosaurs. Being that I was born in 1993 I believe the memory in question is form something in the 90’s or early 2000’s. Here’s what I remember…
This scene is definitely the end or really close to the end of the program. It’s in the style of an animated cartoon (I believe it was a 2dish not a 3d style). Something happens (sorry for being vague) that causes the dinosaur characters to have to leave earth. I think they were on separate little rocketships flying out into space. The camera zooms in on the t-rex in what I remember to be a red rocketship. He looks visibly upset. Then he sheds a tear. I remember it being a very emotional moment.

It sounds like the movie We're Back! A Dinosaur's Story. Near the ending the dinosaurs board a red airship (which could look like a spaceship)




I thought of this right away also :) - they basically have to leave because they were never supposed to be there in the first place - its a fluke of the time traveling spaceship pilot gizmo dude thing that makes them tame and smart and transports them from the dinosaur age to the present -which is why at the end of the movie they can't stay.
